# South is not dropping a table for app actstream

Tags: django, django-south

Trying to drop tables with South for app `django-activity-stream` and then re-add it.

Process I used to drop table:

1. Deleted all previous migrations for the app to start fresh
2. Replaced `models.py` with an empty file
3. `python manage.py schemamigration actstream --initial`
4. `python manage.py migrate actstream`

But when I look at the database, the tables are still there.

Why aren't the tables dropping -- am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process I would use to drop/re-add table:

1. Deleted all previous migrations for the app to start fresh
2. python manage.py schemamigration actstream --initial
3. python manage.py migrate actstream --fake
4. Replaced models.py with an empty file
5. python manage.py schemamigration actstream --auto
6. python manage.py migrate actstream

Maybe you can omit the 3 step

Comment: Yes that's the process for drop/re-add I would think too .... but it's not dropping the table.....

Comment: I noticed that even doing `python manage.py reset actstream` it's also not dropping them